# iOS8 AVAudioEngine how do I route microphone input to the (bottom) speaker output?

Tags: ios8, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I've been able to connect AVAudioInputNode (which takes microphone input data) and connect it to the AVAudioEngine. I can hear the output from the (upper) speaker if I put my phone close enough to my ear. How can I route the audio output to the (bottom) speaker instead ? (Think of it as a loudspeaker..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the `sharedInstance` of your `AVAudioSession`. Then call `setCategory:withOptions:error` passing in the parameters below:

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:Nil];`

Comment: Hi Nick, thx for the reply. I've tried to setup the AudioSession, but I get gibberish environment noise from the (bottom) speaker and if I said something, there's no voice coming out from the speaker...

Comment: Then there's a problem elsewhere in your code. Post a new question specific to the 'gibberish' noise coming out of the lower speaker, post the relevant code and we can go from there.

Comment: Hi Nick, seems like you have had experience in audio related stuff. Can you take a look at my other related question ? Thx. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270127/ios8-avaudioengine-how-to-send-microphone-data-over-multipeer-connectivity

Comment: How do I send PCMBuffer over network ? I use MultiPeer to send, but I have no idea how to convert it back to AVAudioPCMBuffer in didReceiveData. Here's my sending code: `MCPeerID *remotePeerID = [self.sessionMC.connectedPeers objectAtIndex:0]; NSArray *peersArray = @[remotePeerID]; NSError *error = nil; NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer.floatChannelData length:buffer.frameLength]; [self.sessionMC sendData:data toPeers:peersArray withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable error:&error]; if(error) {NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it in swift

```
//In declarations
var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
//In viewDidLoad 
try! audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, options: [.defaultToSpeaker] )
```

Comment: Thank you! :) But I got `Ambiguous reference to member 'setCategory'`Error. For me it worked (Swift 2.2) by removing the error part: `try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DefaultToSpeaker)`